# WSO2 with plugin WS-Trust Authenticator sends saml 1.1 request

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have been trying to set up STS for my wso2 is, but the request it sends is 1.1, and I need SAML 2.0 I cant find anywhere where I can change this configuration.

I need this to be SAML 2.0. Is there a setting I am missing?

This is what I see in SAML tracer:

[image: request desc1]

Answer (score 0):

SAML 1.1 / SAML 2.0 token type is not based on any config on WSO2 IS side. Both are supported by default and the response token type is decided based on the type of token defined in the RST (Request Security Token)

Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/ws-trust/

> Both SAML 1.1 and SAML 2.0 token types are supported by default. The
> issued token type is decided based on the type of token defined in the
> RST (Request Security Token)

You have added the response, in the above-attached image. So first verify the token type of the RST.